# ASP.Net MVC4 Mobile-Aware OutputCache

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on upgrading an application from MVC3 to MVC4 and noticed something that I assumed (hoped?) would "just work".

CODE:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 600, VaryByParam = "none")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

This is a textbook caching example for ASP.Net. Whenever a browser hits the page, it checks the cache to see if something exists, generates the view if not, and then sends the cached results.

This works great; however, playing around with the Mobile view functionality of MVC4, I noticed that the above code does not check to see if the Request is from a Mobile Device.  So if I hit that route on a desktop, the desktop view will be displayed on my phone until cache is invalidated.  The reverse is true as well (if I first hit the page with a phone, the desktop will then see the mobile view instead).

Is there a parameter that I could use to make this work like I hoped or am I looking at building a customer OutputCacheProvider?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After a bit more digging, I found a solution to the issue.

**Updated Controller Action**

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 600, VaryByCustom = "IsMobile")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

**Override GetVaryByCustomString in Global.asax**

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    if (custom.ToLowerInvariant() == "ismobile" && context.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
    {
        return "mobile";
    }
    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
}
```

Comment: Switching to desktop view doesn't work with this code. The page simply refreshes instead of switching. Use context.GetVaryByCustomStringForOverriddenBrowser() instead.

Comment: @PavelChuchuva some time this code not switching to Desktop , Why ?

Comment: @Moslem7026 No idea, sorry. Would you please try to reliably reproduce this problem and then ask another question?

Comment: @PavelChuchuva unfortunately i cant reproduce , but some time it occurs , load mobile cached version for all mobile and desktop requests

Answer (score 5):

This is Correct GetVaryByCustomString method

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
    {
        if (custom.ToLowerInvariant() == "ismobile")
        {
            return context.GetVaryByCustomStringForOverriddenBrowser();
        }
        return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
    }
```

Comment: some times it locks on mobile and not swiched to desktop